# Spring actuator '/auditevents' endpoint returns 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

I am getting a 404 error when invoking `/actuator/auditevents` endpoint. Upon closer look, I see that available endpoint listing doesn't include `/auditevents` endpoint.

`pom.xml` dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

`application.properties`

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

`http://localhost:8080/actuator` output

```
{
    "_links": {
        "beans": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/beans",
            "templated": false
        },
        "caches": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/caches",
            "templated": false
        },
        "caches-cache": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/caches/{cache}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "conditions": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/conditions",
            "templated": false
        },
        "configprops": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/configprops",
            "templated": false
        },
        "env": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/env",
            "templated": false
        },
        "env-toMatch": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/env/{toMatch}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "health": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/health",
            "templated": false
        },
        "health-path": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/{*path}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "heapdump": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/heapdump",
            "templated": false
        },
        "info": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/info",
            "templated": false
        },
        "loggers": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers",
            "templated": false
        },
        "loggers-name": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/{name}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "mappings": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/mappings",
            "templated": false
        },
        "metrics": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics",
            "templated": false
        },
        "metrics-requiredMetricName": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/{requiredMetricName}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "scheduledtasks": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/scheduledtasks",
            "templated": false
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator",
            "templated": false
        },
        "threaddump": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/threaddump",
            "templated": false
        }
    }
}
```

Spring-boot version: `2.2.6.RELEASE`

Not sure whether I am missing any required configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Auditing can be enabled by providing a bean of type AuditEventRepository in your application’s configuration.

Try to add following bean into your app :

```
@Bean
public InMemoryAuditEventRepository repository(){
 return new InMemoryAuditEventRepository();
}
```

Comment: This works. I was expecting this to be automatically configured. Is there a specific reason to configure this explicitly?

Comment: Please read auditing part https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-auditing

Comment: If you have spring security on classpath then it will work out of the box , if not please add those bean to get it working)

Comment: I have spring security as a dependency (see pom.xml above). Still it is not working out of the box

Comment: Please share your code with more details or can you push it on github ?

Comment: Sample repo is available at [https://github.com/sudhirtumati/spring-security-sample](https://github.com/sudhirtumati/spring-security-sample)

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-auditing
From this documenation auditing part 5.7 it says that to enbale auditing you need to add bean

Comment: Only this solution)

Comment: This works for me, but if anyone want more configuration about `auditevents`, here is the link:  https://www.jvt.me/posts/2022/01/13/spring-boot-actuator-audit/